# Transformar variable de javascript a php para usarla posteriormente en una consulta mysql (sin recargar la página)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

He obtenido esta variable en javascript, y ahora me gustaría convertirla a una variable php para que se ejecute en un WHERE de un consulta a mysql. PD: no puedo usar ningún método que requiera recargar la página, porque sino no se ejecuta esta acción: "modal_container2_4.classList.add('show2');"

El código en el que obtengo la variable es el siguiente:

```
<script>
$('body').on('click' , '.button_buscar_user' , function() { 
var IDbutton = $(this).attr('id');
console.log(IDbutton);
document.getElementById('nombregrupo').innerText = IDbutton;        
modal_container2_4.classList.add('show2');
})
          
</script>
```

Y este es el código en el que necesitaría la variable IDbutton pero en php:

```
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM grupos WHERE id = '".$IDbutton."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
 $grupo10 = $mostrar['grupo'];}
?>
```

Cualquier consejo/respuesta/código que consiga que esto funcione sirve. No hace falta necesariamente transformar la variable si se puede hacer de otra forma, esta es la que se me ha ocurrido a mi. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Usa ajax y listo

Answer (score 2):

Con Ajax se envía la variable de JavaScript al server en PHP, dentro del evento on('click') del .button_buscar_user colocal un ajax, seria así:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'url_al_scrpt_php.php',
  type:'post',
  data: { IDbutton } 
});
```

y en el código de PHP colocas esto:

```
 $IDbutton = $_POST['IDbutton'];
```

Comment: No se porque pero no me funciona.